# Using JNDI to configure EJBs: NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, wildfly-8

I have the following structure

```
MyProject.ear  (module name) MyProjectEar
   |----- lib
   |----- META-INF
   |----- MyProject.war
   |----- MyProject.jar (module name) MyProject
```

At MyProject.jar I have several EJBs, including a `mypackages.myproject.ejb.impl.ConfigManager` (which has a local interface in `mypackages.myproject.ejb.local.ConfigManagerLocal`)

`ConfigManager`

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class GestorConfiguracion implements GestorConfiguracionLocal {

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    Context ctx = null;
    try {
      ctx = new InitialContext();
      ctx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      String jndiEnv = (String) ctx.lookup("myProject/srv/environment");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception in jndienv", e);
    }
    try {
      appVersion = (String) ctx.lookup("myProject/buildVersion"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception in buildversion", e);
    }
```

`myProject/srv/environment` is to be local to the server (so it does not change between EAR builds), so it is set in `standalone.xml`, as follows

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
  <bindings>
    <simple name="java:/env/myProject/srv/environment" value="DEV"/>
  </bindings>
  <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

`myProject/buildVersion` will be changed at each building, by adding an `env-entry-value` to the `env-entry`.

I have tried two approachs:

1) Add to MyProject.ear/META-INF/application.xml the lines:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>myProject/buildVersion</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>0.0.1</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>myProject/srv/environment</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>java.lang.String</res-type>
  <lookup-name>java:/env/myProject/srv/environment</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

I only get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`, with the messages:

- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.MyProjectEar.MyProject.ConfigManager.myProject.buildVersion
- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.MyProjectEar.MyProject.ConfigManager.myProject.srv.environment

Answer (score 0):

It ended being that I was looking at the wrong context.

- If the `env-entry` and `resource-ref` tags where in ejb-jar.xml in the EJB project, I will find them in `java:comp/env/` (v.g., `java:comp/env/myProject/buildVersion` and `java:comp/env/myProject/srv/environment`); I needed to change the first lookup to `ctx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");`
- If the `env-entry` and `resource-ref` tags where in application.xml in the EAR project, I will find them in `java:app/env/` (v.g., `java:app/env/myProject/buildVersion` and `java:app/env/myProject/srv/environment`); I needed to change the first lookup to `ctx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:app/env");`